# Can Jackson SerializationFeature be overridden per field or class?

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

Can a (De)SerializationFeature be enabled/disabled per object or per field? I cannot think of a simple way.

To be specific, I have enabled `WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED` for the readability of data fields that rarely expand beyond 1 item. However for some top-level structures, I want to always keep the array-ness. Critique that mix as you will but the general question still stands :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in general way.

But for this particular feature, I think there may be an issue filed to allow such handling already at github. If not, feel free to submit one.

The reason there is no general way is that for many features this level of granularity does not make sense.