# How to apply a Jackson SerializationFeature on one field?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Given the following POJO, I would like to apply `SerializationFeature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED` on the `links` field ONLY.

```
public class HalRepresentation {

   @JsonProperty("_links")
   @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
   private final Map<String, List<Link>> links = new HashMap<String, List<Link>>();

    @JsonProperty("_embedded")
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
    private final Map<String, Object> embedded = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    protected HalRepresentation() {
    }

    public Map<String, List<Link>> getLinks() {
        return links;
    }
    public Map<String, Object> getEmbedded() {
        return embedded;
    }
}
```

I tried to serialize it as follows:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
    .enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED);
try {
    outputStream.write(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(halRepresentation));
    outputStream.flush();
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
}
```

But when I do this the unwrap feature is also applied on the `embedded` field. I tried to find an equivalent annotation for `WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED`, but I can't find one. Do you have an idea for this using Jackson ?

Comment: This does not seem to be possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095754/can-jackson-serializationfeature-be-overridden-per-field-or-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @AlexeyGavrilov, it does not seem to be possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29133209/1225328. A workaround could be to create a custom `JsonSerializer`:

```java
public class SingleElementCollectionsUnwrapper extends JsonSerializer<Object> {

  @Override
  public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    if (!serializers.getConfig().isEnabled(SerializationFeature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED)) {
      new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED).writeValue(gen, value);
    } else {
      gen.writeObject(value);
    }
  }

}
```

Then, annotate the `links` field with `@JsonSerialize`:

```java
@JsonProperty("_links")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
@JsonSerialize(using = SingleElementCollectionsUnwrapper.class)
private final Map<String, List<Link>> links = new HashMap<String, List<Link>>();
```

Comment: Be carefult Instantiating a whole new ObjectMapper for every value, this will be expensive. Also take care to propogate all the configuration from the original mapper, otherwise other unrelated config (eg a default date format) will stop being applied under this object.

Answer (score 2):

It appears additional functionality was added to Jackson 2.6 to allow you to apply this feature to a single field using the @JsonFormat annotation:

```
    @JsonProperty("_links")
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
    @JsonFormat(with = {Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY,Feature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED})
   private final Map<String, List<Link>> links = new HashMap<String, List<Link>>();
```